# How to discard the Duplicate values in ElasticSearch using DSL Query?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-dsl

Here I am trying to get the attribute_name on the basis of query customer the Problem here is there is lots of duplicate value in attribute name which I want to discard , can someone pls help me with this

```
 {
  "_source": [
    "attribute_name"
  ],
  "size": 500, 
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "CUSTOMER",
      "fields": [
        "hierarchy_name",
        "attribute_name"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

LIke suppose this is my output , here I want to discard duplicate attribute_name

```
 {
        "_index": "planlytx_records",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "tD6WDnkBQTXQIneq8Ypr",
        "_score": 2.5454113,
        "_source": {
          "attribute_name": "CUSTOMER"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "planlytx_records",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3j6WDnkBQTXQIneq8Yps",
        "_score": 2.5454113,
        "_source": {
          "attribute_name": "CUSTOMER"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "planlytx_records",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "nT6WDnkBQTXQIneqyonu",
        "_score": 1.8101583,
        "_source": {
          "attribute_name": "REGION"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "planlytx_records",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "6D6WDnkBQTXQIneq8Yps",
        "_score": 1.8101583,
        "_source": {
          "attribute_name": "REGION"
        }
      },
```

Myoutput should be something like this ..

```
{
        "_index": "planlytx_records",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3j6WDnkBQTXQIneq8Yps",
        "_score": 2.5454113,
        "_source": {
          "attribute_name": "CUSTOMER"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "planlytx_records",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "nT6WDnkBQTXQIneqyonu",
        "_score": 1.8101583,
        "_source": {
          "attribute_name": "REGION"
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use [`collapse`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/collapse-search-results.html) parameter, to remove duplicate from your search  result based on field value**

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "attribute_name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "attribute_name": "CUSTOMER-ALL"
}
{
  "attribute_name": "CUSTOMER-ALL"
}
{
  "attribute_name": "CUSTOMER"
}
{
  "attribute_name": "CUSTOMER"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "CUSTOMER",
      "fields": [
        "attribute_name"
      ]
    }
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "attribute_name.keyword"
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67260491",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.12199639,
        "_source": {
          "attribute_name": "CUSTOMER"
        },
        "fields": {
          "attribute_name.keyword": [
            "CUSTOMER"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67260491",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.09271726,
        "_source": {
          "attribute_name": "CUSTOMER-ALL"
        },
        "fields": {
          "attribute_name.keyword": [
            "CUSTOMER-ALL"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Update 1:**

If you just want to delete the duplicate data, you can run the below query

```
{
  "collapse": {
    "field": "attribute_name.keyword"
  }
}
```

Search Result will be

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67276433",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "attribute_name": "CUSTOMER"
        },
        "fields": {
          "attribute_name.keyword": [
            "CUSTOMER"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67276433",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "attribute_name": "REGION"
        },
        "fields": {
          "attribute_name.keyword": [
            "REGION"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Again we need to create new Index

Comment: @Nitesh no need to create a new index again. You can just update your index mapping as --> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#add-multi-fields-existing-field-ex

Comment: "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "planlytx_records",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "sz6WDnkBQTXQIneq8Ypr",
                "_score": 2.5454113,
                
                    "hierarchy_name": "CUSTOMER",
                    "item_pk": "C008",
                    "attribute_name": "CUSTOMER",
                    "@version": "1"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231640/discussion-between-nitesh-and-escoder).

Comment: @Dev Do you expect to get all the data from attribute_name or only those data that have CUSTOMER in them ?

Comment: The requirement is to get all the distinct attribute_name having hierarchy_name as CUSTOMER ..